# When in inheritance, base constructor call virtual method, why the class is Dervied and call Dervied method?

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor

I met a problem. The code below does not run as expected:

```
public class Dervied extends Base {
    private String name = "dervied";
    public Dervied() {
        System.out.println(this.getClass().toString());
        this.tellName();
    }
    public void tellName() {
        System.out.println("Dervied tell name: " + name);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Base base = new Dervied();
    }
}

class Base {
    private String name = "base";
    public Base() {
        System.out.println(this.getClass().toString());
        this.tellName();
    }
    public void tellName() {
        System.out.println("Base tell name: " + name);
    }
}
```

The result is:

```
class Dervied
Dervied tell name: null
class Dervied
Dervied tell name: dervied
```

But why? The environment is jdk1.8.0_60 and Windows 10. When `new Dervied()` run into the `Dervied()` method, and call the base constructor `Base()`. But why the printed class in `Base()` is `Dervied`? And the `this.tellName()` call the method in `Dervied` class as polymorphism?

Comment: Fields are not polymorphic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the reason why we should never call virtual methods from constructors. When a constructor is run, there are various stages. First the base class constructor runs and then the derived class constructor.

So a virtual call will depend on the stage the constructor is in and it may end up calling a method on an object that does not yet exist.

This is the reason why you see null being printed because 'name' instance variable in Derived has not yet been initialized yet because the base class constructor is running and it calls tellName() of the Derived class object.

Here is a relevant quote from Joshua Bloch's Effective Java - 2nd Edition :

> The superclass constructor runs before the subclass constructor, so
>   the overriding method in the subclass will be invoked before the
>   subclass constructor has run. If the overriding method depends on any
>   initialization performed by the subclass constructor, the method will
>   not behave as expected.